# How can I classify HTML Files?

Tags: html, nlp, classification, jsoup

I am trying to classify my HTML files based on their contents. Using JSoup, I have retrieved the title and description portion of the HTML file. And then, using the opennlp Sentence Detector I have identified an array of sentences.

However, I am not sure how to proceed further. I can simply look for certain keywords in those sentences and do the classification, but then again that feels like I am writing a simple `if..else..` statement without using the full potential of NLP.

I would like to train my code to do the classification, but I am not sure how that can be achieved.